# Ui-Router with model data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Using Angular, Ionic, & UI-Router, I'm trying to change states and pass in data to the State Params. With Angular's built in Ng-Route, this was easy but just creating a link in this manner.

```
<a href="state2/{{detail.id}}">Brings me to state 2 with detail about this item</a>
```

But as Ionic has switched to UI-Router, this tends to break the transitions that have been created. I've seen demos where in peoples controllers, the have a click handler that sets up a state change:

```
      $scope.switchState = function(){
        $state.go('abstract.main'); 

        <a ng-click="switchState">Change States</a>
```

This works if the nested state is just a static view. But What I want to know is how to properly change states and pass along the parameters to get the data. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For instance for this state:

```
.state('test', {
    url: '/test/:id',
    templateUrl: 'insertpathhere.html'
})
```

In your controller you can navigate like this:

```
$state.go('test', { id: 420 });
```

Or you can have something like this in your html:

```
<a ui-sref="test({id:detail.id})">Click me</a>
```

Comment: I tried the ui-sref and the state change in the controller but the id doesn't get passed along for some reason.

So right now it reads 

<a ui-sref="state2({id:item.id})">State 2</a>

Comment: Maybe you can post a fiddle or something the same.
You can check out more at https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#wiki-ui-sref

Comment: The issue was actually not related to how I had my links set up, but how I had my mark up. One of my views didn't have a <view> and that threw off the whole thing. I will mark this as answered for your help though. Thanks